# Limit rows on MYSQL query calculation

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to limit the amount of rows that are used to do a calculation in SQL;

```
SELECT    SUM(`position`)/COUNT(`id`) AS `avg`
FROM      rankings_04_06_13
WHERE     site_id = '7'
ORDER BY  `position` ASC
LIMIT     4
```

However when I do this is doesn't change the answer it is as if the calculation already takes place before it reaches the LIMIT and ORDER BY clauses.

Any ideas?

Comment: Use a subquery for the limit, then do the calculation on the subquery result.

Comment: Can you show us the results on both query you tried?

Comment: @DekDekku you cannot use LIMIT in subquery.

Comment: Yea, I meant derived table. Same thing, unless you're giving the IS exam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (like suggested by @DekDekku):

```
SELECT
    SUM(`position`)/COUNT(`id`) AS `avg`
FROM (
    SELECT    `position`,
              `id`
    FROM      rankings_04_06_13
    WHERE     site_id = '7'
    ORDER BY  `position` ASC
    LIMIT 4
) as tmp
```

**UPDATE:** to limit 75% of the rows you can try this (but its not very efficient):

```
SET @c:=0;    
SELECT
    SUM(`position`)/COUNT(`id`) AS `avg`
FROM (
    SELECT    
        `position`,
        `id`,
        @c:=@c+1,
        MOD(@c,4) as m      
    FROM      
        rankings_04_06_13
    WHERE     
        site_id = '7'
) as tmp
WHERE
    m <> 3
```

Comment: Awesome thanks for the code, is there a way to using the subquery to limit it by 75% of the rows instead of having to do it through a separate query to find the 75%?

Comment: np, you need an additional query to calculate the 75%

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example using derived tables. It might be what you're looking for depending on how do you want to apply the limit (you might want to `group by position` to get the first 4 positions rather than the first 4 rows)

```
SELECT SUM(`position`)/COUNT(`id`) AS `avg` 
FROM   (SELECT position, id 
        FROM rankings_04_06_13 
        WHERE site_id = '7' 
        ORDER BY `position` ASC 
        LIMIT 4
) AS AVRG
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cc69c9/6)**

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 SELECT SUM(`position`)/COUNT(`id`) AS `avg`
 FROM   (SELECT position,id from rankings_04_06_13 
 WHERE site_id = '7' 
 ORDER BY  `position` ASC LIMIT 4) as t2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT    SUM(`position`)/COUNT(`id`) AS `avg` 
FROM      (SELECT postion,id from rankings_04_06_13  
WHERE     site_id = '7' 
ORDER BY  `position` ASC LIMIT 4) AS subquery;
```